# how can I edit a hyperlink in a word document by using excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I created a program in excel to send notifications of training courses to the employees who have been nominated on training courses by using a Word document, but I don't know what code I need to use to edit the hyperlink of the location.

```
Sub sendMail()


Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olm As Outlook.MailItem

Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Cell As Range


Set ol = New Outlook.Application

For r = 12 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set olm = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(Range("C8").Value)
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<name>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
     
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<Course_title>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<start_date>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 8).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<end_date>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<Start_Time>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 11).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<End_Time>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 12).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<Duration>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 13).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    
    With wd.Selection.Find
    
        .Text = "<<objectivs>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 14).Value
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With

' I need to paste the location of the training course in the excel table, so that link will be pasted on the "editing hyperlink" in the word document so i don't know the code that create/change the hyperlink that redirects the end user (the employee who has been nominated) to the location of the training course
    
    doc.Content.Copy
    
    With olm

        
        .Display
        .To = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value
        .CC = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value
        .Subject = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7).Value
        
        Set Editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Editor.Content.Paste
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = Range("C4").Value
        .Send
        

    End With


    Set olm = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set doc = Nothing
    wd.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set wd = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next

MsgBox "Notifications have been sent successfully", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Status"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Address` is URL of hyperlink.

```
    sTxt = "<<editing hyperlink>>"
    With wd.Selection.Find
        .Text = sTxt
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            wd.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wd.Selection.Range, _
                Address:="http://www.google.com", _
                TextToDisplay:="location of the training" ' Update as needed
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: I tried this code also but i didn't work 

Comment: May I know what does ` didn't work` mean? Is there "<<editing hyperlink>>" in your doc?

Comment: i mean that the code did not work with me. the error is in these lines (If .Found Then
            Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
                Address:="http://www.google.com", _
                TextToDisplay:="location of the training")                   and the error message is "Run-time error '450':   Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: now the error message is "Automation error" and in the document i found "location of the training" comes at the begining on the document not replaced with <<editing hyperling>> and it linked with google

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try again. `wd` is a Word application reference as your code in OP.

Comment:  good brother you are amaizing thank you so much 

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, the address that the hyperlink should point to is in Sheet1 column 15 and, for example, the placeholder in the Word document is `<<hyperlink>>` then you could use

```
With wd.Selection.Find
    .Text = "<<hyperlink>>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceNone
    If .Found Then doc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=Sheet1.Cells(r, 15).Value, TextToDisplay:="Location of the training course"
End With
```

This `With` block needs inserting into your code in the right position (i.e. in the same place in the order that `<<hyperlink>>` appears in your document).

Obviously you can change the "Location of the training course" text to whatever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately brother it didn't work. it shows to me an error "Wrong number of arguments"

Comment: On which line is the error (the line that is highlighted when you press 'Debug' in the error dialog)?

Comment: @AbuAli were you able to get this working? If not, please advise the line that the error is on

Comment: in this line.   If .Found Then doc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=Sheet1.Cells(r, 15).Value, TextToDisplay:="Location of the training course"